# fs2 streams: testing an fs2 server

Tags: scala, stream, side-effects, fs2

I have a stream in this form:

```
val server = for {
  _ <- Stream.eval(initTasks)
  serverBinding <- Stream.eval(...)
} yield serverBinding
```

I understand that in order to run it, I should do something like:

```
server
  .compile
  .drain
  .unsafeRunAsync(_ => ())
```

Now, I want to write unit-tests for this server, but I can only run my tests when the server is all set-up. Currently, in my `beforeAll` block, I have:

```
testServer
  .interruptWhen(shutdownSignal)
  .compile
  .drain
  .unsafeRunAsync(_ => ())

Thread.sleep(5000)
```

and in my `afterAll` block, I have:

```
shutdownSignal.set(true).unsafeRunSync()
```

to bring down the server after my test.

I was wondering if I could use signals to achieve my stated goal so that I can somehow "wait" on the signal so that the tests are run only once the signal is up. Alternatively I'd love to know of the generic/idiomatic way of doing this.

Comment: Are you doing integration testing? Or is this supposed to be unit tests? If it's the latter, I'd argue that you don't need to set up FS2 in order to test your core business logic.

Comment: my bad, you are right. I meant integration test.

Comment: you can see my current solution to this problem in my posted answer btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fs2 had this construct called [Promise](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/7ad702a21e4af95e188cff9a7352ff3bc17beabd/core/shared/src/main/scala/fs2/async/Promise.scala) which can be used for this purpose. It's now [deprecated](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/pull/196) but Cat's [Deferred](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/concurrent/Deferred.scala) can be used. So before running `compile.drain` on the stream, we can make the stream complete the promise/deferred value and then in the `beforeAll` we can wait on its value.